# Application windows always open on the top left corner of the screen on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, window-manager

I find this a highly annoying "feature" on a wide screen monitor that my mostly used apps - terminal and gedit always open directly under the top-left corner of my screen and I have to drag them to my eye position each and every-time.

I have tried installing the CompizConfig Settings Manager and using the feature to position  windows centre, but this has had no effect - the force feature here isn't working for me either.

I can use e.g. gnome-terminal --geometry=140x50+50+50 for the terminal but this doesn't work for gedit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Actually I found a solution for GNOME without compiz.

You can either use

- [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/850/place-windows-in-center/) if you have gnome-shell < v3.14
- or open dconf and set `center-new-windows` in `org.gnome.mutter` to `true`:
  [image: dconf open with org.gnome.mutter -> center-new-windows]

Comment: For the interested the following command-line command will do the above mentioned `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter center-new-windows true`

Answer (score 2):

You can set in in compiz. It works for me.

```
Window Management -> "place plugin" -> Fixed Window Placement -> Windows with fixed positions
example: gedit 200 200 keep-in-work-area-to-yes
```

or

```
Window Management -> "place plugin" -> General -> Window position : Centered
```

Comment: Can you be specific? I have All | 400 | 300 set for "Windows with fixed windows" and All | Centered for "Windows with fixed placement mode" - gedit still pops up top left

Comment: `All` is wrong - use `any`

Comment: didnt work either

Comment: try turning off position-related plugins - they may collide

Comment: I turned everyone off earlier

Comment: and if you try to turn on the windows centering in the general tab? everything of this works for me...

Comment: It worked for me.